# Python Regular Expression to match multiple occurrences of word

Tags: python, regex

I want to use `re.search` (or, more precisely, `pandas.str.contains`) to match a string whenever it contains the word 'car' at least two times (or exactly two times, whatever is easier). As an example, consider the two strings

```
string1 = 'Car, Cat, House, Car'
string2 = 'Car, Cat, House'
```

The regex expression I am searching for should match `string1`, but not `string2`. I was playing around with look ahead (things like `Car(?=Car)`), but got completely weird behaviour (unsurprisingly, I never got a handle on regex...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern you are looking for is `Car.*?Car`, that is two occurences of `Car`, separed by anything (or nothing at all). This will match any string containing at least two occurences of `Car`:

```
re.search(r"Car.*?Car", string1)
```

The non-greedy star `*?` will make sure `re.search` stops as soon as two occurences are found.

If `string1` contains line terminators, also add the `re.MULTILINE` flag.